# How to handle asynchronous users data in JS socket.io chat?

Tags: javascript, sockets, asynchronous, socket.io

I have a chat application that adds/removes users.
These are events driven by socket.io

I then acces users by usernames like

```
displayData(users[username]);
```

Problem is.. that users[username] can be removed on asynchronous call that  socket.io calls on my script.

This will raise an error and will stop all script.

How can I handle that:

Even if I test it like

```
if (users[username]) displayData(users[username]);
```

it may happen than user is deleted just after test.

This happens on browser JS side.

Answer (score 0):

First off, If you are maintaining your own user list, then you should update that list on connect and disconnect events so it is never out-of-date.

Second off, the browser (in this regard) is single threaded.  The list cannot be changed between the time you test it with `if (users[username])` and the time you access the list later in the same line of code.  It can only be changed when the currently running activity has returned back to the system so the system can then run another activity (which might change it).

Different asynchronous actions will happen only when one action has yielded - allowing any action to take place.  This works with an event queue.  When an asynchronous action occurs, it places an item in the event queue.  That item will only start some code running when no other code is running and when that item gets to the top of the queue.  This ensures that only one action ever actually runs at the same time.  This is true in both a browser and in node.

---

If you have code in a client that wants to know instantly whether some other user has already disconnected, you simply cannot know that.  There are delays in propagating events to other clients notifying them that someone has left the chat so you will not ever have perfectly up-to-date info at each client.  Depending upon exactly what you are trying to do, there are ways of dealing with the imperfectness of this information.  You'd have to describe in more detail what problem you're trying to solve for us to suggest a work-around.

Comment: I am talking about JS on browser side, not the server side.

Comment: @user300675 - other than how you maintain the list, the answer is the same either way.  The JS is single threaded in the browser so the list will not change between the time you test it and the time you act on it.